# How to use pjax in yii2 to update a column in Yii2?

Tags: php, ajax, yii, yii2, pjax

I want to use pjax in views/viewfile/index to update state of row of database after clicking on a button. How can do that step by step, in which file write JavaScript code and in which file get data from AJAX?

```html
<?php
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

Pjax::begin();
echo GridView::widget([...]);
Pjax::end();

?>
```

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\LaptopSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Laptops';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="laptop-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Laptop', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>
 <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin('id' => 'rp1'); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'network',
            'technology',
            'sup_id',
            'speaker',
   'size',
   [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{myButton}' , // the default buttons + your custom button
            'buttons' => [
                'myButton' => function($url, $model, $key) {     // render your custom button
                    return Html::a('تایید');
                }
            ]
   ],
   
     // [
           // 'class' => DataColumn::className(), // this line is optional
           /* 'attribute' => 'name',
            'format' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Name',
        ],*/
            // 'optical_drive',
             //'webcam',
            // 'touchpad',
            // 'card_reader',
            // 'ethernet',
            // 'vga',
            // 'hdmi',
            // 'usb3_ports',
            // 'usb2_ports',
            // 'usb_type_c',
            // 'thunderbolt_ports',
            // 'serial_ports',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
 <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

How to save state in database onclick('mybutton')? In which file should call jquery for ajax?

Answer (score 0):

is there any particular reason to use pjax?

you can write your js code either in your view file using
$this->registerJs(" your js code goes here");
or in a separate js file and get it loaded on this page.

the data you will receive via ajax request in your controller/action..
once you receive the data, you can put your logic to work and update the database row.

Comment: thank you.you re right but is there any complex example about it

Comment: Yes, definitely. For complex js part, we prefer writing js in separate file and configure your app to auto include the js file with same name as that of view. That should handle all your complete js and implementation would be neat

Comment: I'd suggest, when you make the button using yii syntax, in the option parameters, you can give id, class, data-attribute, and almost anything you want

Comment: Is your issue Solved ?

Comment: in url of that we should type name of action in controller?

Comment: Yes, the URL parameter in ur js code corresponds to your action in controller generally mentioned as controller/action

Comment: <?php

$url = \yii\helpers\Url::to([
    'laptop/test1', 
    'param1' => '01', 
    'param2' => '02', 
    'param3' => '03'
]);
$js = <<< JS
    $('#ss1').click(function(){
 alert('ffa');
    $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
               alert('arefff');              
            }
        })
 
   // alert('eeee');
    });
 
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);

?>

Comment: and in laptopcontroller i have :


 public function actionTest1(){
    if(isset(Yii::$app->request->post('test'))){
        $test = "Ajax Worked!";
        // do your query stuff here
    }else{
        $test = "Ajax failed";
        // do your query stuff here
    }

    // return Json    
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($test);
 }